# Проблема с обновлением элементов во ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Есть TabLayout который при старте содержит по умолчанию 4-е элемента, количество этих таб и их содержимое может меняется. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

Если при запуске сразу удалить одну из 4-х и потом снова добавить  одну тестовую, то сама таба добавиться новая(тестовая) а страница во ViewPager останется таже.

А если при запуске сначала добавить одну(5-ю) потом удалить две последних 5 и 4-ю и снова одну создать, то на месте все той же 4-й страници уже будет уже тестова страница во ViewPager и тестовая таба.

Т.е проблема в том, что страницы во ViewPager не удаляются.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        setupTabIcons();

        findViewById(R.id.btnAddTab).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addTab();
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.btnRemoveTab).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                removeTab();
            }
        });
    }

    private void addTab() {
        adapter.addFragment(new TestFragment(), "test");
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("test"));
    }

    private void removeTab() {
        int position = tabLayout.getTabCount() - 1;
        adapter.removeFragment(position);
        tabLayout.removeTabAt(position);
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_contacts));
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_outcoming));
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_me_call));
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_card));
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

        adapter.addFragment(new MainContactsFragment(), "Contacts");
        adapter.addFragment(new MainOutcomingCallsFragment(), "Outcoming Calls");
        adapter.addFragment(new MainOutcomingCallsFragment(), "Incoming Calls");
        adapter.addFragment(new MainCardFragment(), "Cards");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    /**
     * Fragment adapter
     */

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            Log.d(TAG, "addFragment( " + fragment.getClass().getSimpleName() + " )" + " position:" + mFragmentList.size());

            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void removeFragment(int position) {
            Log.d(TAG, "removeFragment( " + position + " )");
            if (!mFragmentList.isEmpty() && position < mFragmentList.size()) {
                mFragmentList.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }


            Log.d(TAG, "ViewPager count: " + this.getCount());

        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            // return mFragmentTitleList.get(position); to display icons + text
            // return null to display only the icon
            return null;
        }

        public List<Fragment> getmFragmentList() {
            return mFragmentList;
        }

        public void setmFragmentList(List<Fragment> mFragmentList) {
            this.mFragmentList.clear();
            this.mFragmentList.addAll(mFragmentList);
        }

    }
}
```

Для наглядности:

**Случай номер один**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Случай номер два**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вам надо удалять фрагменты, лучше использовать FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Comment: а в чем разница?

Comment: @Bringoff Все, погуглил, получилось! опубликуйте ответ!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` вместо `FragmentPagerAdapter`. Он лучше предназначен для `Pager`-а, в котором надо добавлять-удалять фрагменты на лету.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в адаптер добавить вот [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16793871/3212712):

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

Comment: не помогло, при чем обратил внимание что при первом варианте, если сначала четвертую табу -> удалить -> и снова добавить на ее место тестовую, то все ок, а если ее сначала  открыть четвертую табу  -> удалить -> и снова добавить на ее место тестовую то страница во ViewPager не меняется